# make the array even?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

You are given an array A of N integers. If you make the array whole using the following operation, then what is the minimum number of operations required to make the entire array even?

**Note**  : It can be proved that this is always possible.

##### Operation

Select an index

and perform operation:

P=A[i]+A[i+1]; Q=A[i]-A[i+1];

A[i]=P; A[i+1]=Q;

[link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/bit-manipulation/basics-of-bit-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/make-even-8ced0d4b/) to whole question

this is my code

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    N=int(input())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    dic=[i for i in range(N) if arr[i]%2!=0 ]
    value=0
    for i in range(len(dic)-1):
        k=dic[i+1]-dic[i]
        value+=k
    print(value)
```

testcases.............

```
testcase1:
         N=6
         arr= 1 6 4 3 4 2
         my output = 3
         expected output = 4
```

i do not get how come four operations is need in this testcase were as it only need three operation .

```
  testcase 2:
           N=6
           arr = 1 6 4 3 5 2
           my output = 4
           expected output =3
```

in this testcase all the integers will not be converted into even number no matter how many operations we applied .

if someone could show me how come testcase2 is done in three operation .

testcase1 will be done in four operation .

and were i am doing it wrong

can it be solved with bit manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in this testcase all the integers will not be converted into even number no matter how many operations we applied .

- Yes they can be. See my below solution.

The idea is simple. I haven't used any bit manipulation, but here is how I would do it ,

- odd +/- odd = even
- odd +/- even = odd

For an `i`, if `A[i]` is even, I wouldnt care. Consider all `i`, such that `A[i]` is odd.

- If A[i+1] is odd, I have P= odd+odd and Q=odd-odd, both even in one operation. I'll increase count by 1.
- If A[i+1] is even, I have P=odd+even and Q= odd-even, both odd. I have done one operation. Now, I have two odds, one more operation and I can make both even. So, I'll increase count by 2.

> if someone could show me how come testcase2 is done in three operation .

- **Operation 1** : `[1 6 4 3 5 2]` -> `[7 -5 4 3 5 2]` , `A[0] = A[0] + A[1]`, `A[1] = A[0] - A[1]`
- **Operation 2** : `[7 -5 4 3 5 2]` -> `[2 12 4 3 5 2]`, `A[0] = A[0] + A[1]`, `A[1] = A[0] - A[1]`
- **Operation 3** : `[2 12 4 3 5 2]` -> `[2 12 4 8 -2 2]`, `A[3] = A[3] + A[4]`, `A[4] = A[3] - A[4]`

> can it be solved with bit manipulation.

- I think you can [check odd even using bitwise operations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-using-bitwise-operators/), other than that, I don't think so.

Here is a possible implementation :

```
def count_ops(A,n):
    count = 0 
    i = 0 
    done_last = False
    while(i < n-1):
        if(A[i]%2 == 0):
            i+=1
            continue
        if(i == n-2):
            done_last = True
        if(A[i+1]%2 == 0):
            count += 2
        else:
            count += 1
        i += 2
    if(not done_last):
        if(A[n-1]%2 == 1):
            count += 2
    print(count)
    return count
```

Notice the `done_last` flag, I'll leave it up to you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code you can try for your problem.

```
def countOperations(arr, n) :
 
    count = 0;
 
    # Traverse the given array
    for i in range(n - 1) :
 
        # If an odd element occurs
        # then increment that element
        # and next adjacent element
        # by 1
        if (arr[i] & 1) :
            arr[i] += 1;
            arr[i + 1] += 1;
            count += 2;
 
    # Traverse the array if any odd
    # element occurs then return -1
    for i in range(n) :
        if (arr[i] & 1) :
            return -1;
 
    # Returns the count of operations
    return count;
 
if __name__ == "__main__" :
 
    arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
    n = len(arr);
    print(countOperations(arr, n));
```

Comment: hey if we passed testcase1 array to this code it is giving answer 6 .which is wrong